# Cannot RDP in to a server 2016 VM in VirtualBox from a Win 10 host

Tags: windows-10, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I have a Win 10 host that I am trying to RDP into a server 2016 VM in VirtualBox,

I can ping one machine from the other. I have tried disabling the firewall and antivirus and giving the Server a static IP but I still cannot connect.

I'm struggling with this concept.

Comment: Try puttin your Guest Machines on Bridged Networking so they have IP addresses on your router.  I RDP between Host and Guests frequently.  Make sure the Guest machines have Network Discovery and File/Print sharing turned ON.

Comment: Also, you may need to log out of the Server to log in via RDP.

Comment: Tried logging out and it didnt work

Comment: Also tried enabling network sharing on the host and vm and that didnt work either

Comment: Spin up a new, test Guest machine and try RDP into that. Try a Windows guest.  If you try a Linux Guest you need to install XRDP and start the RDP service. Log out of a Guest before trying to RDP into it.

Comment: Thanks I spun up another vm and I got a login prompt then I got an error which pointed me to download KB4103723 but that failed to install even though I installed Edge. Any pointers please? cheers in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go into System Properties (Just run systempropertiesadvanced) on the server and make sure you have RDP enabled and add the specified user. By default whatever the admin account is it will generally be added.

Comment: I already have remote connections enabled on both machines. Im already using a bridged adapter on both machines. However I cannot ping the default gateway that my router is giving out. So im still stuck

Comment: Do you have another NIC you can add to the system and pass through to the VM for further testing?

Comment: Im not sure if that would make a difference as ive tried a bridged adapter, internal and NAT and nothing works. My friend beleives its not DNS as I cant ping my routers default gateway on the 192.168.1. network